# Getting financial news headlines on a given month

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I never had the chance to learn about web-scraping. 
I was wondering what it it I can add to the code below in order to get headlines for a given time period?
If it is possible to only get financial news, that would be great!

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen

news_url="https://news.google.com/news/rss"
Client=urlopen(news_url)
xml_page=Client.read()
Client.close()

soup_page=soup(xml_page,"xml")
news_list=soup_page.findAll("item")
# Print news title, url and publish date
for news in news_list:
    print(news.title.text)
    print(news.link.text)
    print(news.pubDate.text)
    print("-"*60)
```

Comment: A function like this would be ideal:
get_headlines(start_date, end_date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt at a solution. Check the get_headlines(start_date,end_date) method I included at the end.

I convert the format in the XML that you scraped into a datetime object, and I compare it to other datetime objects I specify to produce a boolean value. We can tell if an article falls within our range based on the booleans that are displayed and then select those articles only.

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from datetime import datetime

news_url="https://news.google.com/news/rss"
Client=urlopen(news_url)
xml_page=Client.read()
Client.close()

soup_page=soup(xml_page,"xml")
news_list=soup_page.findAll("item")
# Print news title, url and publish date
for news in news_list:
    print(news.title.text)
    print(news.link.text)
    print(news.pubDate.text)
    print("-"*60)
    print("Date Object: ", datetime.strptime(news.pubDate.text, "%a, %d %B %Y %X %Z"))

    sample_end_date = "Wed, 08 May 2019 18:17:04 GMT"
    print(datetime.strptime(sample_end_date, "%a, %d %B %Y %X %Z") > datetime.strptime(news.pubDate.text, "%a, %d %B %Y %X %Z"))
    #datetime of article is less than the datetime of the end date

    sample_start_date = "Wed, 08 May 2019 00:00:00 GMT"
    print(datetime.strptime(sample_start_date, "%a, %d %B %Y %X %Z") < datetime.strptime(news.pubDate.text, "%a, %d %B %Y %X %Z"))
    #datetime of article is greater than the datetime of the start date


   #If both values are true, then we know that the article falls within the range we specified. If not, then it falls outside the range.'''
def get_headlines(start_date= input("Enter start date. \nFollow this format exactly for date input Wed, 08 May 2019 18:17:04 GMT: \n"), end_date= input("Enter end date. \n")):
    start_date_object = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%a, %d %B %Y %X %Z")
    end_date_object = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%a, %d %B %Y %X %Z")
    news_url="https://news.google.com/news/rss"

    Client=urlopen(news_url)
    xml_page=Client.read()
    Client.close()

    soup_page=soup(xml_page,"xml")
    news_list=soup_page.findAll("item")
    # Print news title, url and publish date
    print(f"All articles from {start_date_object} to {end_date_object}: \n")
    for news in news_list:
        if (end_date_object>datetime.strptime(news.pubDate.text, "%a, %d %B %Y %X %Z")>start_date_object):
            print(news.title.text)
            print(news.link.text)
            print(news.pubDate.text)
            print("-"*60)



get_headlines()
```

Here is the sample output from midnight on Wednesday GMT to 18:00 Wednesday GMT:

Enter start date.

Follow this format exactly for date input Wed, 08 May 2019 18:17:04 GMT:

Wed, 08 May 2019 00:00:00 GMT

Enter end date.

Wed, 08 May 2019 18:17:04 GMT

All articles from 2019-05-08 00:00:00 to 2019-05-08 18:17:04:

Trump briefed on Colorado shooting, White House says - Fox News
https://www.foxnews.com/us/trump-briefed-on-colorado-shooting-white-house-says-politicians-offer-condolences

### Wed, 08 May 2019 08:08:22 GMT

Iranian leader announces partial withdrawal from nuclear deal - CNN
https://www.cnn.com/2019/05/08/middleeast/iran-nuclear-deal-intl/index.html

### Wed, 08 May 2019 09:40:00 GMT

China backtracked on nearly all aspects of US trade deal: Sources - CNBC
https://www.cnbc.com/2019/05/08/china-backtracked-on-nearly-all-aspects-of-us-trade-deal-sources.html

### Wed, 08 May 2019 03:12:00 GMT

Barr's top aide has seen the Russia probe like few in Trump's world - POLITICO
https://www.politico.com/story/2019/05/08/brian-rabbitt-william-barr-1309751

### Wed, 08 May 2019 09:03:00 GMT

WH instructs former counsel not to comply with congressional subpoena - ABC News
https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/white-house-instruct-counsel-comply-congressional-subpoena/story?id=62873987

### Wed, 08 May 2019 00:10:00 GMT

Trump Holds Rally In Florida Panhandle, With Disaster Relief Funds Held Up - NPR
https://www.npr.org/2019/05/08/720803270/as-hurricane-relief-stalls-in-d-c-trump-to-rally-base-in-florida-panhandle

### Wed, 08 May 2019 09:01:00 GMT

Colorado STEM school student Brendan Bialy helped disarm gunman - NBC News
https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/colorado-stem-school-student-brendan-bialy-helped-disarm-gunman-n1003181

### Wed, 08 May 2019 09:52:00 GMT

Pompeo on surprise Iraq visit amid rising Iran tensions - Aljazeera.com
https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2019/05/pompeo-surprise-iraq-visit-rising-iran-tensions-190508034718722.html

### Wed, 08 May 2019 04:18:00 GMT

In South Africa Election, Ramaphosa Faces Verdict From Disillusioned Voters - The New York Times
https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/08/world/africa/south-africa-election.html

### Wed, 08 May 2019 07:39:49 GMT

Lahore explosion: At least six dead in blast near Sufi shrine - CNN
https://www.cnn.com/2019/05/08/asia/lahore-blast-intl/index.html

### Wed, 08 May 2019 06:15:00 GMT

Uber drivers set to protest around the world ahead of the company's $90 billion IPO - CNBC
https://www.cnbc.com/2019/05/08/uber-drivers-strike-over-low-wages-benefits-ahead-of-ipo.html

### Wed, 08 May 2019 08:51:13 GMT

Billionaire Charlie Munger Compares Bitcoin Investors to ‘Judas Iscariot’ - Ethereum World News
https://ethereumworldnews.com/billionaire-charlie-munger-compares-bitcoin-investors-to-judas-iscariot/

### Wed, 08 May 2019 00:21:12 GMT

Android TV will benefit once Assistant is linked to live TV guide data - Engadget
https://www.engadget.com/2019/05/08/google-assistant-epg-android-tv-play-store/

### Wed, 08 May 2019 08:35:40 GMT

Kim Kardashian prison reform: Kim Kardashian West has helped free 17 people from prison in the last 90 days - CBS News
https://www.cbsnews.com/news/kim-kardashian-west-has-helped-free-17-people-from-prison-in-the-last-90-days/

### Wed, 08 May 2019 05:07:00 GMT

Vampire Weekend Perform With Haim on “Fallon”: Watch - Pitchfork
https://pitchfork.com/news/vampire-weekend-perform-with-haim-on-fallon-watch/

### Wed, 08 May 2019 04:40:00 GMT

George Clooney reveals Harry and Meghan's royal baby shares his birthday - Daily Mail
https://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-7004777/George-Clooney-reveals-Prince-Harry-Meghan-Markles-newborn-shares-birthday.html

### Wed, 08 May 2019 06:59:43 GMT

Oakland A's pitcher Mike Fiers throws 2nd career no-hitter, beats Reds - Fox News
https://www.foxnews.com/sports/athletics-fiers-pitching-no-hitter-beats-reds

### Wed, 08 May 2019 06:36:18 GMT

Joe Namath hasn’t had a drink since his embarrassing moment on live TV - NBC Sports
http://profootballtalk.nbcsports.com/2019/05/07/joe-namath-hasnt-had-a-drink-since-his-embarrassing-moment-on-live-tv/

### Wed, 08 May 2019 01:28:00 GMT

Mariners fall to .500 with another bullpen collapse that leads to 5-4 loss in Bronx - Seattle Times
https://www.seattletimes.com/sports/mariners/mariners-fall-to-500-with-another-bullpen-collapse-that-leads-to-5-4-loss-in-bronx/

### Wed, 08 May 2019 03:20:00 GMT

Move over, silicon switches: There's a new way to compute - Phys.org
https://phys.org/news/2019-05-silicon.html

### Wed, 08 May 2019 07:19:31 GMT

NASA asteroid: Space agency sheds light on daring asteroid defence plan - ‘Ideal target' - Express.co.uk
https://www.express.co.uk/news/science/1123704/NASA-asteroid-double-redirection-test-NASA-DART-asteroid-Didymos

### Wed, 08 May 2019 07:43:00 GMT

RFK Jr. Is Our Brother and Uncle. He's Tragically Wrong About Vaccines. - POLITICO
https://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2019/05/08/robert-kennedy-jr-measles-vaccines-226798

### Wed, 08 May 2019 09:05:00 GMT

Answer (score 0):

Try `feedparser`:

```
import feedparser
news_url=r'https://news.google.com/news/rss'
fp = feedparser.parse(news_url)

## number of entries
len(fp['entries'])
```

Output:

```
38
```

Title of article at index '0':

```
print(fp['entries'][0]['title'])
```

Output:

```
School Shooting in Colorado Leaves 1 Student Dead and 7 Injured - The New York Times
```

Print all info for entry at index '0':
    fp['entries'][0]

Output:

```
{'title': 'School Shooting in Colorado Leaves 1 Student Dead and 7 Injured - The New York Times',
 'title_detail': {'type': 'text/plain',
  'language': None,
  'base': 'https://news.google.com/rss?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en',
  'value': 'School Shooting in Colorado Leaves 1 Student Dead and 7 Injured - The New York Times'},
 'links': [{'rel': 'alternate',
   'type': 'text/html',
   'href': 'https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/07/us/colorado-school-shooting.html'}],
 'link': 'https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/07/us/colorado-school-shooting.html',
 'id': '52780288859641',
 'guidislink': False,
 'published': 'Wed, 08 May 2019 00:56:15 GMT',
 'published_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=8, tm_hour=0, tm_min=56, tm_sec=15, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=128, tm_isdst=0),
 'summary': '<ol><li><a href="https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/07/us/colorado-school-shooting.html" target="_blank">School Shooting in Colorado Leaves 1 Student Dead and 7 Injured</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#6f6f6f">The New York Times</font></li><li><a href="https://www.foxnews.com/us/injuries-reported-unstable-situation-shots-fired-at-colorado-school-sheriff-says" target="_blank">Colorado school shooting leaves at least 1 dead, 7 injured, 2 in custody, sheriff\'s office says</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#6f6f6f">Fox News</font></li><li><a href="https://www.cnn.com/2019/05/07/us/colorado-denver-area-school-shooting/index.html" target="_blank">Eight injured in school shooting in suburban Denver, 2 suspects are in custody</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#6f6f6f">CNN</font></li><li><a href="https://kdvr.com/2019/05/07/president-trump-briefed-on-highlands-ranch-school-shooting/" target="_blank">President Trump briefed on Highlands Ranch school shooting</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#6f6f6f">FOX 31 Denver</font></li><li><a href="https://www.oregonlive.com/nation/2019/05/sheriff-school-shooting-near-denver-injures-at-least-7.html" target="_blank">Sheriff: School shooting near Denver injures at least 7</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#6f6f6f">OregonLive</font></li><li><strong><a href="https://news.google.com/stories/CAAqcQgKImtDQklTU2pvSmMzUnZjbmt0TXpZd1NqMEtFUWo1dV9ueWpZQU1FVWE5TGp2Z2NDNFJFaWhUYUc5MGN5Qm1hWEpsWkNCaGRDQnpZMmh2YjJ3Z2FXNGdTR2xuYUd4aGJtUnpJRkpoYm1Ob0tBQVAB?oc=5" target="_blank">View full coverage on Google News</a></strong></li></ol>',
 'summary_detail': {'type': 'text/html',
  'language': None,
  'base': 'https://news.google.com/rss?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en',
  'value': '<ol><li><a href="https://www.nytimes.com/2019/05/07/us/colorado-school-shooting.html" target="_blank">School Shooting in Colorado Leaves 1 Student Dead and 7 Injured</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#6f6f6f">The New York Times</font></li><li><a href="https://www.foxnews.com/us/injuries-reported-unstable-situation-shots-fired-at-colorado-school-sheriff-says" target="_blank">Colorado school shooting leaves at least 1 dead, 7 injured, 2 in custody, sheriff\'s office says</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#6f6f6f">Fox News</font></li><li><a href="https://www.cnn.com/2019/05/07/us/colorado-denver-area-school-shooting/index.html" target="_blank">Eight injured in school shooting in suburban Denver, 2 suspects are in custody</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#6f6f6f">CNN</font></li><li><a href="https://kdvr.com/2019/05/07/president-trump-briefed-on-highlands-ranch-school-shooting/" target="_blank">President Trump briefed on Highlands Ranch school shooting</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#6f6f6f">FOX 31 Denver</font></li><li><a href="https://www.oregonlive.com/nation/2019/05/sheriff-school-shooting-near-denver-injures-at-least-7.html" target="_blank">Sheriff: School shooting near Denver injures at least 7</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#6f6f6f">OregonLive</font></li><li><strong><a href="https://news.google.com/stories/CAAqcQgKImtDQklTU2pvSmMzUnZjbmt0TXpZd1NqMEtFUWo1dV9ueWpZQU1FVWE5TGp2Z2NDNFJFaWhUYUc5MGN5Qm1hWEpsWkNCaGRDQnpZMmh2YjJ3Z2FXNGdTR2xuYUd4aGJtUnpJRkpoYm1Ob0tBQVAB?oc=5" target="_blank">View full coverage on Google News</a></strong></li></ol>'},
 'source': {'href': 'https://www.nytimes.com', 'title': 'The New York Times'}}
```